# Stick a div to left of page

Tags: html, css

I have a container and inside I have a div I wanted to stick to the left corner of the screen, but I always have a gap

How do I obtain something like this? Thanks in advance

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=22090721B1B171B7!12771&authkey=!AEDRyX0320pmcLk&v=3&ithint=photo%2cjpg

Comment: Please provide a js fiddle or similar to what you're doing.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vvLe4xz5/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i hope to help with this example https://jsfiddle.net/step/L9rn4fkg/ you play with margin-top

```
.sticky {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #30cff0;
  margin-top:50px;
  z-index:1000;
}
```

Comment: If you want the div to stick to the left of the screen you'll need to remove the `margin: auto;` inside `#cont`

Comment: You have two options

1) Moves .sticky above #cont and add margin-left
2) Change width the #cont at 100% and remove margin: auto;

Answer (score 1):

The most basic way to reach this is:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

And make sure your `div` doesn't have any `margin` or `padding` on the left side either (for instance, when you use [bootstrap](/questions/tagged/bootstrap)'s `class="container"` it will give you a left and right padding of 15px.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should reset your body(or your elements parent of you want stick) margin.
you can use:

```css
* { /* it's a hard method */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


.fix-el {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  
  /* center it */
  line-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #EEE;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="fix-el">
    fix this
</div>
```

hope you can solve it